# Syntax errors Java Bukkit Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, syntax-error, bukkit

I tried myself on a bukkit plugin. I started with a little heal plugin, but i got some syntax errors here, would be awesome if you guys can help me with that, and explain it to me! thanks :)

Im getting this error on the last line:

Multiple markers at this line
   - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody
   - Syntax error, insert "else Statement" to complete 
   BlockStatements

```
package P1;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.Effect;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class ultimateHeal extends JavaPlugin {

@Override
public void onEnable() {

    System.out.println("uHeal by xGumBax activated!");
}

@Override
public void onDisable() {

    System.out.println("uHeal by xGumBax deactivated!");
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, String[] args) {
    if(cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("heal")) {
    if(!(sender instanceof Player)) {

        System.out.println("Dieser Befehl ist nur für Spieler!");
        return true;

    }
    Player p = (Player) sender;
    if(args.length == 0) {
        if(p.hasPermission("uheal.heal.self")) {
            p.setHealth(20);
            p.setFoodLevel(40);
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + getDescription().getName() + "]" + ChatColor.GRAY + " Deine Lebensanzahl wurde aufgefüllt.");
            p.playEffect(p.getLocation(), Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES, 1);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + getDescription().getName() + "]" + ChatColor.GRAY + " Du hast keine Rechte um diesen Befehl auszuführen!");
            return true;
        }



    }
    else if(args.length == 1) {
        if(p.hasPermission("uheal.heal.others")) {
        Player target = this.getServer().getPlayer(args[0]);
        target.setHealth(20);
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + getDescription().getName() + "]" + ChatColor.GRAY + " Spieler " + args[0] + " wurde geheilt!");
        target.playEffect(target.getLocation(), Effect.MOBSPAWNER_FLAMES, 1);
        target.playEffect(target.getLocation(), Effect.POTION_BREAK, 1);
        target.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + getDescription().getName() + "]" + ChatColor.GRAY + " Du wurdest geheilt!");  
    } else {
        p.sendMessage(ChatColor.DARK_RED + "[" + getDescription().getName() + "]" + ChatColor.GRAY + " Du hast keine Rechte um diesen Befehl auszuführen!");
    }

    return false;
}















}
```

Comment: Hi - welcome to stackoverflow. If you could also show the compilation errors that you are receiving it makes it much easier for us to help.

Comment: i added the error i got now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have mis-matching brackets in your `onCommand` method.

The bracket at the end of your code finishes one of the if statements, but you do not have a bracket that finishes the method, or one that finishes the class.

If you add another two brackets at the end of your code, this problem should disappear. I'd encourage you to use your IDE or editor to help you to check that the brackets match correctly.

Comment: If you are using an IDE, then they often have code formatting rules built in to them. This will automatically indent your code and make finding these sorts of errors much easier.

Comment: where can i find IDEs ?

Comment: Eclipse is a good start point  it's free, well featured and heavily used. It _does_ take a bit of getting used to, and can be downloaded from https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Comment: yes, i coded this with eclipse..and i wasnt able to find it without your help lol